# Formatting background color of all cell addresses in arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, format

I made arrays with all cells in them that I want to format the background color of. But I can't seem to use the data in the arrays at all. Is there a way to select the cell addresses of all arrays at once and formatting them?

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
Sub resizer()

    Dim years(), selector As Variant
    Dim r As range
    Dim years1 As String: years1 = year(Now) + 1 & "/" & year(Now) + 2 & "E"
    Dim yearscounter As Long, loopcounter As Long





   For Each r In range("A3", "J200")

        If r.Offset(0, 9).value = years1 Then
        
             yearscounter = yearscounter + 1
            
             ReDim Preserve years(1 To 10, 1 To yearscounter)
            
             For loopcounter = 1 To 10
                 years(loopcounter, yearscounter) = r.Offset(0, loopcounter - 1).address
                 
             Next loopcounter
   
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no single command to find all matching cells in a range. However, your approach is good by checking each cells in the range and collect their address in a buffer. I would use a `Union` to do this, like this:

```
  Dim rUni As Range
  Set rUni = Nothing

  For Each r In range("A3", "J200")
    If r.value = years1 Then
        If rUni Is Nothing Then
           Set rUni = Range(r.Offset(0, -9), r)
        Else
           Set rUni = Union(rUni, Range(r.Offset(0, -9), r)
        End If
    End If
  Next r
  Debug.Print rUni.Address
```

There is a minor risk of failure in the above code if the value of year1 is found to the left of column J, so I would change the loop to

```
  For Each r In Range("J3:J200")
```

Anyhow, there's no point checking those cells where you do not expect year value.

When you finished collecting the target cells, you can apply formatting on all affected cells this simple:

```
  rUni.Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(....
```